# Piwik Custom Variable in joomla not working

Tags: php, mysql, joomla1.5

I have added this code to set a custom variable

```
piwikTracker.setCustomVariable(
          1, // Index, the number from 1 to 5 where this Custom Variable name is stored for the current page view
          "username", // Name, the name of the variable, for example: Category, Sub-category, UserType
          "santosh", // Value, for example: "Sports", "News", "World", "Business", etc.
          "visit"
        );
```

and I have generated a url like

```
http://localhost/news_wire/index.php?option=com_content&username=santosh&view=category&id=1&Itemid=2
```

and when I click in visitors->custom variable nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

Check you are looking at the right date, your code is correct.